# Dynamic Google Maps based on Autocomplete Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to create dynamic Google map based on Autocomplete Input. I have written the code as:-

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeAtURNzEX26_mLTUlFXYEWW11ZdlYECM&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map_options = {
  center: {
    lat: 19.0825223, 
    lng: 72.7411155
  },
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sale_map_canvas'),map_options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position:{
     lat: 19.0825223,
     lng: 72.7411155
   },
   map:map,
   draggable:true
});
var city_options = {
   types: ['(cities)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
}
var locality_options = {
   componentRestrictions: {country:"in"}
}
var city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('sale_city'),city_options);
var locality = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('sale_locality'),locality_options);
google.maps.event.addListener(city,'place_changed',function(){
var places = city.getPlaces();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i,place;
for (i = 0; place=places[i]; i++) 
{
console.log(place.geometry,location);
bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(15);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(locality,'place_changed',function(){
var places = locality.getPlaces();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i,place;
for (i = 0; place=places[i]; i++) 
{
 console.log(place.geometry.location);
 bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
 marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(15);
});
</script>

 <body>
 <input id="sale_city" name="sale_city" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required>
 <label for="sale_city">City</label>

<input id="sale_locality" name="sale_locality" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required>
<label for="sale_locality">Locality</label>
<div id="sale_map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

The Map isn't showing up. Please Solve it..I've written the code by referring the video on https://youtu.be/2n_r0NDekgc

Comment: There is no div with id="sale_map_canvas" in your HTML.

Comment: I did add div with id="sale_map_canvas". But still it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the code.

1. Map div "sale_map_canvas" is missing.
2. Map should be loaded on page load.

I have changed the code and now map is loading

```
<style>
#sale_map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var map;

function initialize() {

var map_options = {
  center: {
    lat: 19.0825223, 
    lng: 72.7411155
  },
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sale_map_canvas'),map_options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position:{
     lat: 19.0825223,
     lng: 72.7411155
   },
   map:map,
   draggable:true
});
var city_options = {
   types: ['(cities)'],
   componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
}
var locality_options = {
   componentRestrictions: {country:"in"}
}
var city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('sale_city'),city_options);
var locality = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('sale_locality'),locality_options);
google.maps.event.addListener(city,'place_changed',function(){
var place = city.getPlace();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

console.log(place.geometry,location);
bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(15);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(locality,'place_changed',function(){
var place = locality.getPlace();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 console.log(place.geometry.location);
 bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
 marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setZoom(15);
});



};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


</script>

 <body>
 <input id="sale_city" name="sale_city" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required>
 <label for="sale_city">City</label>

<input id="sale_locality" name="sale_locality" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="on" placeholder="" required>
<label for="sale_locality">Locality</label>
<div id="sale_map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not working.. Can you do one thing i.e. create a JSFiddle and give me the link

Comment: Strange. Can you copy paste the html in a file and see. It is working for me. I will give you the fiddle link shortly

Comment: I did copy it.. But still it isn't working!!! That's why I said to upload on JSfiddle